# cocos2d :: CCmoveTO

Tags: cocos2d-x, ccaction

Hi, i am new to cocos2dx programming........

I am trying to make a projectile motion of a target sprite

// in addtarget() part

```
int i(0);
while(i<20)
{
p=HelloWorld::nextPoint(p,0.5);//p is a struct see below.

cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction* actionMove=cocos2d::CCMoveTo::actionWithDuration(1.0, ccp(p.x,p.y));
target->runAction( cocos2d::CCSequence::actions(actionMove,NULL));
++i;
}
cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction* actionMoveDone = cocos2d::CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget( this,callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::spriteMoveFinished));

target->runAction( cocos2d::CCSequence::actions(actionMoveDone, NULL) );
```

nextPoint is a function which returns struct p(which have time,velocity and space coordinates t,x,y,vx,vy)
When outside the loop, it runs all fine but when inside it doesn't show anything
debugging done and all cordinates are fine
Tried removing NUll can't do
Finally using bezier so now it works partially.
But unable to understand why CCMoveTo doesn't work. it always showed initial coordinates of (60,60) 
& also some good tutorial link for cocos 2dx for people who r new to mobile game programming. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure that it makes sense running multiple `MoveTo` actions on the same target. Indeed, you are saying to the same target to move at different locations at the same time, this cannot produce any reliable result.

You could try using `MoveBy`, where you specify an incremental displacement, but most probably you will need to rework the logic of your code, if what you want is that you target follows a given trajectory. In this case, you could create a larger sequence containing all of the `MoveTo` actions you need to run. E.g. (in pseudo code):

```
 cocos2d::CCSequence* actionSequence = <create empty sequence>;
 while(i<20)
 {
     p = HelloWorld::nextPoint(p,0.5);
     cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction* actionMove = ...
     <add actionMove to actionSequence>
     ++i;
 }

 target->runAction(actionSequence);
```

Comment: i am not moving them on the same time......I have used action with duration here. But i got ur point.. I have reworked my logic. thnx... I also need to know how to delay in that earlier case inside the while loop. And your method also worked. thnx a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code...

```
while(i<20)
{
p=HelloWorld::nextPoint(p,0.5);//p is a struct see below.

cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction* actionMove=cocos2d::CCMoveTo::actionWithDuration(1.0, ccp(p.x,p.y));
cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction* actionMoveDone = cocos2d::CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget( this,callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::spriteMoveFinished));

target->runAction( cocos2d::CCSequence::actions(actionMove,actionMoveDone,NULL));
++i;
}
```

Check for syntax.. Hopw this helps.. :)

Comment: Sorry didn't work, I have also deleted the part of sprite move finished :function calling.

Answer (score 1):

**CCSequence::actionsWithArray** so sequence 20 MoveTo and callfunc after

```
CCArray * arr = CCArray::arrayWithCapacity(20);
for(int i = 0; i != 20; i++)
{
    p = HelloWorld::nextPoint(p,0.5);
    arr->addObject(CCMoveTo::actionWithDuration(1.0, ccp(p.x,p.y)));
}

CCFiniteTimeAction * actionMoveDone 
= CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget(this,callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::spriteMoveFinished));
target->runAction(CCSequence::actions(CCSequence::actionsWithArray(arr), actionMoveDone, NULL));
```